# C++ topic: Using "getline" in conjunction with "If If else"

Tags: c++, if-statement, getline

I have a question regarding using getline with and If/ Else If statement.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
    int yourAge = 13;

        cout << "What's your age dude? ";

           if(yourAge < 21) {

        cout << "What? " << yourAge << "? You're too young to drink!!! " << endl;

         } else if(yourAge >= 21) {

         cout << "Cool!" << yourAge << "? You are good to go.  Don't drink    and drive!" << endl;

      }
        return 0;

  }
```

This works fine.  yourAge is 13 and the result is that it says "You're too young to drink".

However, I want to introduce the getline function into the code, so that the result depends upon the user's input.  I attempted to change code as below:

```
      int yourAge;

      cout << "What's your age dude? ";

       getline(cin, yourAge);

        if(yourAge < 21) {

       cout << "What? " << yourAge << "? You're too young to drink!!! " << endl;

} else if(yourAge >= 21) {

    cout << "Cool!" << yourAge << "? You are good to go.  Don't drink and drive!" << endl;

}

return 0;    
   }
```

This, in turn, results in this error message whenever I try to compile:

```
  "ctut.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
   ctut.cpp:25:25: error: no matching function for call to        ‘getline(std::istream&, int&)’
 getline(cin, yourAge);
                     ^
   ctut.cpp:25:25: note: candidates are:
   In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:90:0,
             from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/cwchar:44,
             from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/postypes.h:40,
             from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/iosfwd:40,
             from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/ios:38,
             from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/ostream:38,
             from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/iostream:39,
             from ctut.cpp:1:
  /usr/include/stdio.h:442:9: note: ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)
  ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict, FILE *    __restrict)      __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);....."
```

That's just the beginning, it goes on for quite a while.

Any help would be appreciated on how to modify.  I would like to get the user input on user age, and depending upon the input, to spit out the correct message on the screen.

Thank you!

Comment: [`getline(cin, yourAge);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) isn't going to work worth a darn unless `yourAge` is a `std::string`. Is the crux of this that you're trying to parse per-line data?

Comment: Sorry WhozCraig, I don't think I'm trying to parse per-line data.  I'm just a beginner and was trying to get be able to write something that would allow me to input data as a user, and based on my input, to output different text.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline),

> `getline` reads characters from an input stream and places them into a string.

Hence `getline()` will work only if your variable `yourAge` is a `std::string`.
For reading `int`, `std::cin` is more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

if you must use "getline()" for whatever reason, you have to convert the string to int:

```
int yourAge;
string age;

cout << "What's your age dude? ";

getline(cin, age);
yourAge = stoi(age);

if(yourAge < 21) {

    cout << "What? " << yourAge << "? You're too young to drink!!! " << endl;

} else if(yourAge >= 21) {

    cout << "Cool!" << yourAge << "? You are good to go.  Don't drink and drive!" << endl;

}
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks war1oc - this worked!  Just a beginner so I believe I need all the help I can get!

Comment: you're welcome :)

u should use "cin >> yourAge" instead of "getline()" tho

Answer (score 1):

`getline()` is used to read strings not integers. You are better off using `cin>>yourAge;` for this program. Read these links to learn more about getline [link1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) [link2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getline()` to read integers, but it is not advisable. It is better to read integers using `cin`.

If you want to read integers using `getline()`, don't forget to convert them into integers using `stoi()`.